# Error Handling for executing multiple sub shell scripts in parallel

Tags: shell, unix, error-handling, parallel-processing, ksh

I have few child shell scripts which needs to be run in parallel. To run these scripts in parallel I am using the following command

```
sh abc.sh "Hi" & sleep 60 & sh abc.sh "Hello" & sleep 60 & sh abc.sh "how";
var_err=$?
if [ $var_err != 0 ]; then
            flag=FAIL
            MASTER_RUN_STATUS_UPDATE "$flag"
            break;
        else
            flag=SUCCESS
            MASTER_RUN_STATUS_UPDATE "$flag"
        fi
```

How to handle errors for each of the above subshell scripts. I want to return the status as success if all the 3 subshell scripts are succeeded and vice versa for fail. Each subshell should be executed after 100s. However using the above syntax, I can only get the status of the last executed process.

Please help me how to achieve this.

Note: I dont have GNU parallel

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you do not have GNU Parallel? http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: Since it is a client server and we are restricted to install GNU parallel

Comment: are you allowed to write your own scripts?

Comment: Yup, in dev server. i doubt in prod

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted "Each subshell should be executed after 100s" as "killed after 100 seconds":

```
results=/tmp/results_
rm ${results}* 2>/dev/null

date
(sleep 4; echo $? > ${results}1)&
subproc_1=$!
(sleep 9;  echo $? > ${results}2)&
subproc_2=$!
(sleep 5; false; echo $? > ${results}3)&
subproc_3=$!

(sleep 100; kill ${subproc_1} ${subproc_2} ${subproc_3}) &
wait ${subproc_1} ${subproc_2} ${subproc_3}

date
for i in {1..3}; do
   # only display result when resultfile exists
   test -f ${results}$i && printf "Process %d: Result %d\n" $i $(cat ${results}$i)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for each script and collect its exit status with this simple pattern:

```
abc.sh Hi   & PID1=$!
abc.sh Hello& PID2=$!
abc.sh how  & PID3=$!

if wait $PID1 && wait $PID2 && wait $PID3
then    flag=SUCCESS
else    flag=FAIL
fi
```